# Apache nifi java.net.UnknownHostException: e2a2e8ab6b6b: Name or service not known

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi

Hi All I faced a small issue with the nifi cluster am creating with the below docker-compose file

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - efactory-network
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:1.9.2
    ports:
      - 8080:8080 # Unsecured HTTP Web Port
      - 8081:8081

    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE=true
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT=8082
      - NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING=zookeeper:2181
      - NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT=1 min
      - nifi.security.needClientAuth=false
    networks:
      - efactory-network
    volumes:
      - state:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/state
      - conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/conf
      - content:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/content_repository
      - db:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/database_repository
      - flowfile:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/flowfile_repository
      - provenance:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/provenance_repository
      - logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/logs
      - data:/opt/nifi/nifi-1.9.2/data
    extra_hosts: 
      - nifi.at:159.69.214.42

networks:
  efactory-network:
    external:
      name: security-network                       

volumes:
  conf:
  content:
  db:
  flowfile:
  provenance:
  logs:
  state:
  data:
```

I persisted data with docker volumes. So state of the cluster should be persisted on a docker-compose restart . I think it's persisted but  giving the below error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ffcca3db4879
```

I will be much grateful if someone can help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Can you add on your nifi:

```
 depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```